# How does the probability depend on the number of turning points?

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, binomial-distribution

For a simple one dimensional unbiased random walk, how does the probability depend on the number of turning points? For instance, if you have a drunk and an infinite line of lampposts and you are given that the total number of steps is $N = 100$ and the number of turning points is $T = 5$ (points where the drunk changes direction), how will this modify the simple binomial distribution?

Comment: Related: https://medium.com/i-math/the-drunkards-walk-explained-48a0205d304.  I might be wrong, but I would think the degrees of freedom is important.

Comment: Do you mean to say that whatever the direction of travel of the drunkard when he reaches the lamppost he shall reverse it with certainty at the next step?

Comment: FWIW, if you receive no good answers, you might want to try [stats.se] or [math.se]

Comment: I have voted to close because this question is mathematics, it does not require any application of physics concepts or principles.

Comment: @sammy gerbil, This question is a part of the 2-6 problem from Feynman and Hibbs QM & Path integrals book. I need to know how binomial distribution depends on the number of turning points to find the path integral for relativistic particle in 1 dimension. Moreoveer, the random walk problem is essential in statistical mechanics and serves as a starting point to derive binomial and gaussian distributions.

Comment: @RuslanMuhamadiarov Addition and subtraction are also essential in physics, but that does not make the question 1+1=? a question about physics.

Comment: @Deep, not necessarily. He can change his direction after a random number of lampposts he pass. It could be one, it could be six, we don't know. However, I am certain that number of turning points will determine the standard deviation. Although I don't quite know how.

Comment: @KyleKanos, Thank you.

Comment: Definitely not a question for CrossValidated. // For a simple random walk, the number of times one changes direction in $N$ steps has mean $$2p(1-p)N$$ hence an estimate of $p$ based on $T$ turns would solve $$\hat p(1-\hat p)=\frac{T}{2N}$$ predictably yielding two values $\hat p$ and $1-\hat p$, and the position $X_N$ after $N$ steps now has distribution $$P_{\hat p}(X_N=2k-N)={N\choose k}\hat p^k(1-\hat p)^{N-k}$$

Comment: @Did, Thank you very much for your reply! I would upvote if I could.